# Representation and degree

Tags: representation-theory

I'm a bit new to representation theory of finite groups, so please forgive me. I'm having trouble figuring out the relationship between the degree(s) of the representation and group that I am representing. So I realize that $S_3 $ has the trivial representation (degree 1), a sign representation (degree 1), and a degree two representation. Why does it stop there? Why can't we have a representation of degree 3? Can you tell from the start that the highest degree that a representation of $S_3$ can have is 2?

More generally, how do you find representations of symmetric groups, besides the trivial representation? If there is no general method, how does one start finding representations of each degree? I'm not even sure how to start finding representations of $S_4$ if I was told to do so. Thanks!

Comment: The regular representation of a finite group $G$ has degree $|G|$ which contains all irreducible representations. See texts on representation/character theory for more details.

Comment: See my [character table of $S_4$ answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554153/character-table-of-group/2554485#2554485) for some advice.

Answer (score 1):

First thing we need to mention is that a finite group has a finite set of nonequivalent irreducible representations.

Now, from Schur's Lemma and the Great Orthogonality Theorem, we can deduce a powerful result. For a finite group, where $ord(G)=N$ and $n_i$ is the dimension of an irreducible representation, following formula applies:
$$ N=\sum_i n_i^2 $$
So, lets take group $S_3$. That group has $3!=6$ elements. It is trivial to see that the only way to write number $6$ as a sum of squares is the following:
$$ 6=1^2+1^2+2^2 $$
While it's easy to find the squares for smaller groups, there is no general way to do it for larger ones. Trial and error is the only way.

*A. Zee - Group theory in a nutshell for physicists, Princeton University Press [2016]*